# Complex Firebase security rules

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have a table in the firebase database called "Discussions" and it shows some posts created by users.

I would like to create a rule on the database level, so it will not show the posts if the user account has been deleted.

An example node looks like this:

```
"Discussions" : {
"36" : {
  "-Ldjrrzfo5K94KT2tjBM" : {
    "content" : "text",
    "from" : "lOkhKOJBNEZuvXt2Zgzz5tUr4ft2",
    "time" : 1556655079442
  }
```

I tried the following rule for that:

```
"Discussions" : {
  "$lan_id": {
".write": "auth != null",
      "$node_id" : {
        ".read": "root.child('Users').child(root.child('Discussions').child($lan_id).child($node_id).child('from').val()).child('deleted').val() != true",
        ".validate": "newData.child('time').isNumber() && newData.child('from').isString() && newData.child('content').isString()"
    }
  }
}
```

This is an example deleted user:

```
"Users" : {
"lOkhKOJBNEZuvXt2Zgzz5tUr4ft2" : {
  "aboutme" : "AAADEFAULT",
  "birthdate" : "01.01.1970",
  "city" : "Deleted",
  "deleted" : true,
  "image" : "default",
  "name" : "Deleted Account",
  "online" : 0,
  "register_date" : 0,
  "sex" : 1,
  "thumb_image" : "default",
  "whyhere" : "AAADEFAULT"
}
```

But that will not work because if I put the "read" rule inside  "$node_id" that will not show any records even if I set directly like this:

```
"$node_id" : {
    ".read": true
 }
```

But I need to access the "$node_id" as well in order to make what I want to do.

Is there any way to create a rule like this?

Answer (score 0):

You have some syntax errors in there.

1. To pass the value of `$lan_id` to `child()` it should **not** be in quotes. If you write `child('$lan_id')` then `'$lan_id'` is just a string. To pass the value of the captured `$lan_id` segment in the path, you'll want `child($lan_id)`.
2. The while `child(root.child('Discussions')...` part looks weird. It's impossible for me to say if it's correct, since the JSON you showed doesn't contain the `deleted` property that your rules check for, but it looks unusual.

I'd expect something closer to this:

```
"root.child('Users').child('Discussions').child($lan_id).child($node_id).child('from').child('deleted').val() !== true"
```

Note that you can also use `parent()` to traverse up the tree, so something like this might also work:

```
"data.parent().child('from/deleted').val() !== true"
```

If you have this rule under the `$node_id` level of your rules, then the call to `parent()` brings you up to `$lan_id`

Comment: Sorry, I guess my question was not clear enough. I edited a bit the question and added a deleted user node.

As you see there is a "deleted" property there in the user's information. What I want to do is, if the user is deleted it should not show the "discussion" created by that user

My problem is if I put the rule under $node_id, it does not show anything

Comment: So basically I want to get the userID with "from" property in the discussion and check if that user is deleted. If yes, then it should not show the discussion.

Comment: Security rules can't be used to filter data. They merely determine whether the read operation (or query) is allowed.

Comment: So while you can secure access to a specific document, you won't be able to securely query the collection, since there's no way to include a condition on a field in another collection in your query.